# Analyze sensory evaluation data using Friedman Test in R?

Tags: r

I searched the site but I can't find similar to my case (or maybe I haven't look hard).

I have a sensory data with a structure similar to this:

```
set.seed(0)
testDT <- data.frame(Panelist = rep(c(1:20), each = 4),
                     Treatment = rep(c(1:4), times = 4),
                     Taste = round(runif(n = 80, min = 5, max = 9), digits = 0),
                     Texture = round(runif(n = 80, min = 5, max = 9), digits = 0),
                     Appearance = round(runif(n = 80, min = 5, max = 9), digits = 0),
                     Color = round(runif(n = 80, min = 5, max = 9), digits = 0),
                     Aroma = round(runif(n = 80, min = 5, max = 9), digits = 0))

head(testDT)
```

There are 20 panelists and 5 attributes, each with 4 replicates. This are the scores of each panelist to the food products developed with varying amounts of identified ingredients (the treatments). Treatment 1 is the control.

My questions:

1. How do I make this data in format to be analyzed for Friedman Test?
2. How to perform this in R?
3. If ever I reject the null hypothesis, what post-hoc test should I perform and how to do it in R?

Thank you.

Comment: `PMCMRplus` contains `friedmanTest()` and it's documentation should provide an example as a starting point. The package also contains different options for post-hoc such as Conover test, Nemenyi test, etc.